# addHandlerAsync() issues on Mac Outlook

Tags: angular, office-js, outlook-web-addins

In our Outlook add-in, we have a pinnable task pane that updates itself based on changes in the current item in the user's inbox. Our app is in AngularJS. The relevant code is like so:

```
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, 
(eventType: Office.EventType) => {
  $state.reload();
});
```

This works fine on Outlook Windows. On Mac, however, we have 2 problems:

1) The first time you scroll through inbox the task pane appears in a new, pop-up window.

2) Many times (at least 50% of cases) the selected item is not set and so our UI is blank.

Ideas? Again, these problems do not happen on Windows.

Comment: `$state.reload()` reloads the current and the parent controllers if any, when you select another email, does the new message data gets sent to the controller?

Comment: $state.reload() always gives a correct result on Outlook Windows ... it is only on Outlook Mac that the code above has problems.

Answer (score 0):

As of 11/7/2018, pinnable task panes are only supported on Windows and Outlook Onilne: [See here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane)

> Pinnable task panes are currently supported by Outlook 2016 for Windows (build 7668.2000 or later for users in the Current or Office Insider Channels, build 7900.xxxx or later for users in Deferred channels) and Outlook Online.

They will probably work intermittently on OS X, but there are no guarantees.